# Php file upload from form to email

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am trying to get a file to upload as part of a contact form, i would like the uploaded file to end up as an attachement to an email that i can then download once i have received said email. I have got the form to work but instead of coming through as an attachment my file comes through like this;

```
--==Multipart_Boundary_xc99bf5ef644b3e51650e68e4b9538cffx
Content-Type: application/pdf;
name="360x260mm Side Seam Pocket 01 - 1up B2.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjggMCBvYmoNPDwvTWV0YWRhdGEgOSAwIFIvT0NQcm9wZXJ0aWVzPDwv
RDw8L09OWzEwIDAgUl0vT3JkZXIgMTEgMCBSL1JCR3JvdXBzW10+Pi9PQ0dzWzEwIDAgUl0+Pi9Q
YWdlcyAyIDAgUi9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2c+Pg1lbmRvYmoNOSAwIG9iag08PC9MZW5ndGggMTM0NTEv
U3VidHlwZS9YTUwvVHlwZS9NZXRhZGF0YT4+c3RyZWFtDQo8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIg
aWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/Pgo8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2Jl
Om5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjAtYzA2MCA2MS4xMzQ3NzcsIDIw
MTAvMDIvMTItMTc6MzI6
```

---

```
Here is my php;




 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    $email_to = "matthew.p@cawthornes.co.uk";

    $email_subject = "website html form submissions";


    function died($error) {
        //  error code 
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
      }

     // validation expected data exists
     if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['service']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])){
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }


    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $service = $_POST['service']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    /* GET File Variables */
    $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 



    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    if (file($tmpName)) {
     /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
     $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
     fclose($file);

     /* a boundary string */
     $randomVal = md5(time());
     $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

     /* Header for File Attachment */
     $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
     $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
     $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";

     /* Multipart Boundary above message */
     $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
     "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $message . "\n\n";

     /* Encoding file data */
     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    }





    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Service: ".clean_string($service)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
    $email_message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  



    function IsInjected($str)
    {
     $injections = array('(\n+)',
                '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
     $inject = join('|', $injections);
     $inject = "/$inject/i";
     if(preg_match($inject,$str))
     {
     return true;
     }
     else
     {
     return false;
     }
    }
    ?>

    <!-- success html -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

    <?php
    }
    die();
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two words: [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use  [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Docs : [Swift Mailer Documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

Downloads : [Swift-5.1.0](http://swiftmailer.org/download)

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  // Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Your subject')

  // Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

  // Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

  // Give it a body
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

  // And optionally an alternative body
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

  // Optionally add any attachments
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Where and how do i use this?

Comment: See : http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html also in my answer i have added a link to documentation and downloads

Comment: Sorry i cant seem to figure out how to apply this to my form ?