# attaching file to an email

Tags: php, forms, email

I have this form to send an email and the visitor can send an attachment with his email as will everything gos well the email sent but the attachment comes to the email like this

> if he uploaded any C.V the C.V will be attached to this Email
>     --_1_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc   Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative; boundary="_2_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc"
>
> --_2_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc   Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset="UTF-8"   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> --_2_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc--
>     --_1_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc   Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream; name="Yousef.txt"
>     Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64   Content-Disposition: attachment
>
> --_1_c4fe3315ccb7d6076c71d64ec5265ecc--

I can see my attached file name but no attachment come with email

**the HTML form**

```
<form id="sendYourCV" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                  class="padding_16px">

                <div class="padding_16 clear_both">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form"><label for="cSector">القطاع :</label></p>
                    <select name="cSector" id="cSector" class="styled-select f_right">
                        <?php
                        $getSections = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM career_selection_sec_arabic");
                        $getSections->execute();
                        $res = $getSections->get_result();
                        while ($s = $res->fetch_object()) {
                            echo "<option value='$s->sector'>$s->sector</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="padding_16 clear_both">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form"><label for="cAdministration">الادارة :</label></p>
                    <select name="cAdministration" id="cAdministration" class="styled-select f_right">
                        <?php
                        $getSections = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM career_selection_admin_arabic");
                        $getSections->execute();
                        $res = $getSections->get_result();
                        while ($a = $res->fetch_object()) {
                            echo "<option value='$a->admin'>$a->admin</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="padding_16 clear_both">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form"><label for="cBranch">الفرع :</label></p>
                    <select name="cBranch" id="cBranch" class="styled-select f_right">
                        <?php
                        $getSections = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM career_selection_bran_arabic");
                        $getSections->execute();
                        $res = $getSections->get_result();
                        while ($s = $res->fetch_object()) {
                            echo "<option value='$s->branch'>$s->branch</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="padding_16 clear_both">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form"><label for="cCareer">الوظيفة :</label></p>
                    <select name="cCareer" id="cCareer" class="styled-select f_right">
                        <?php
                        $getSections = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM career_selection_car_arabic");
                        $getSections->execute();
                        $res = $getSections->get_result();
                        while ($s = $res->fetch_object()) {
                            echo "<option value='$s->career'>$s->career</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form">الاسم :</p>
                    <input name="cName" type="text" class="form_textarea_rec f_right" placeholder="اسمك"/>
                </div>
                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form">التليفون :</p>
                    <input name="cTelephone" type="text" class="form_textarea_rec f_right" placeholder="تليفونك"/>
                </div>
                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form">الايميل :</p>
                    <input name="cEmail" type="text" class="form_textarea_rec f_right" placeholder="بريدك الالكتروني"/>
                </div>
                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form">الرسالة :</p>
                <span class="margin_49px">
                  <textarea name="cMessage" class="form_textarea_vertical_2 f_right m_left_6px" placeholder="رسالتك"
                            type="text"></textarea>
                </span>
                </div>
                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="padding_16 clear_both m_top_10px">
                    <p class="f_right complaints_form">سيرتك الذاتية :</p>
                    <input type="file" name="upFile" id="upFile" class="f_right" style="direction:rtl;"/>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn_main m_bottom_18px m_left_286px"
                       value="ارسل"/>
            </form>
```

this is my form code that I used

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sector = $_POST['cSector'];
    $cAdministration = $_POST['cAdministration'];
    $cBranch = $_POST['cBranch'];
    $cCareer = $_POST['cCareer'];
    $name = $_POST['cName'];
    $telephone = $_POST['cTelephone'];
    $cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'];
    $cMessage = $_POST['cMessage'];

    $recipient = 'info@test.com';
    $subject = "Someone apply for career";

    $myCv = $_FILES['upFile']['name'];
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['upFile']['tmp_name'])));
    $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));

    $content = "This information is for someone who apply for your new career\n
    Sector Applied For:" . $sector . ",\n
    Administration Applied For:" . $cAdministration . ",\n
    Branch Applied For:" . $cBranch . ",\n
    Career Applied For:" . $cCareer . ",\n
    His Name Is: " . $name . ",\n
    His Phone Number: " . $telephone . ",\n
    His Message: " . $cMessage . ",\n
    His Email: " . $cEmail . ",\n if he uploaded any C.V the C.V will be attached to this Email
    --_1_$boundary
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

    --_2_$boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    --_2_$boundary--
    --_1_$boundary
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$myCv\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment

    $attachment
    --_1_$boundary--";

    $headers = "From:info@test.com\r\nReply-To:info@test.com";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $sent = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
    if ($sent) {
        header("Location:index.php?pid=17&carr=your message has been sent, we will contact you soon.");
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
```

I copied this code from some online tutorial but can't understand why it does not go will with the attachment

thanks in advance

Comment: Save yourself the pain, find a library that does the MIME for you.

Comment: Not only the mime, but also the security (header injection, etc). It really is good to understand what happens under the hood, but you don't need to reinvent an already really nice existing wheel.

Comment: @Quentin can you please give an example where can I find this library or any app that do this job thanks

Comment: @Mkky google. `php mail library`

Comment: @Mikky see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361536/php-file-upload-from-form-to-email/23361637#23361637)

Comment: @Mikky Add your HTML form code also with your question it will make me more clear what mistake you are doing. so that I can give you any solution for that.

Comment: @Deepak Goswami here you are

Comment: http://swiftmailer.org/ http://swiftmailer.org/ http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** I guess you are putting extra space for `content-type declaration` code in `His mail:`. See my code there is no need for spaces before that if you will give space it will produce error.

Now the working code with correct formatting is given below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sector = $_POST['cSector'];
    $cAdministration = $_POST['cAdministration'];
    $cBranch = $_POST['cBranch'];
    $cCareer = $_POST['cCareer'];
    $name = $_POST['cName'];
    $telephone = $_POST['cTelephone'];
    $cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'];
    $cMessage = $_POST['cMessage'];

    $recipient = 'info@test.com';
    $subject = "Someone apply for career";

    $myCv = $_FILES['upFile']['name'];
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['upFile']['tmp_name'])));
    $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));

    $content = "This information is for someone who apply for your new career\n
    Sector Applied For:" . $sector . ",\n
    Administration Applied For:" . $cAdministration . ",\n
    Branch Applied For:" . $cBranch . ",\n
    Career Applied For:" . $cCareer . ",\n
    His Name Is: " . $name . ",\n
    His Phone Number: " . $telephone . ",\n
    His Message: " . $cMessage . ",\n
    His Email: " . $cEmail . ",\n if he uploaded any C.V the C.V will be attached to this Email
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$myCv\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

    $headers = "From:info@test.com\r\nReply-To:info@test.com";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $sent = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
    if ($sent) {
        header("Location:index.php?pid=17&carr=your message has been sent, we will contact you soon.");
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Since it worked for me with your HTML code.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Yes it did but something gone wrong with the body message, yes I try you code it worked like cream but now it just sends the attached file and not the body message. thanks @Deepak Goswami

Comment: can you please tell me did it sends the attached file and the email body with you try this code or just tested the attached file thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
function mailWithAttachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message, $totalmailsent)
{
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\n\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $header .= $message."\n\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\n\n";
    $header .= $content."\n\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if(mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You give this a try and let me if fixed, since I'm using this with native php mail

Comment: Thanks @shatheesh but what is the `$path` the `$filename` will be in my example `$myCv` but what is the `$path` will be dose it the place where the attached file will be saved on the server? also I didn't get `$totalmailsent` what dose it mean thanks

Comment: yes,path is the absoulte path where the html resides.. Ah sorry, `$totalmailsent` is the variable that i use in my project. kindly ignore that.. If my answer is helpful you could vote that indeed

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code along with **swiftmailer** to do the job.

```
function send_email_attachment($email, $name, $filename) {

//return $email; //exit;
// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('username')
  ->setPassword('password')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$the_message = "Hi {$name},<br/> Your booking is CONFIRMED and the invoice pertaining to the booking is attached with this mail. <br/> ";

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('email' => 'name'))
  ->setTo(array($email => $name))
  ->setBody($the_message, 'text/html')
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filename))
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
//if ($result){ return 'DONE';}else{    return 'SORRY';}
return;
}

?>
```

This worked well when I used it for one of the sites which I helped in developing and I hope it will work for you too.

N. B.: You will need to get swiftmailer to make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using a simplified library such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial)? It handles most of the parts that take you excessive time for you, you wouldn't need to add headers and all that - it's done for you.

Example:

```
    $mail=new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //host through which the mail should be sent
    $mail->Host="smtp.mydomain.com";              

    //address where the email is going to be sent from
    $mail->From="me@mydomain.com";       

    //address where the email is going         
    $mail->AddAddress("person@otherdomain.com");

    //subject for the email  
    $mail->Subject="Example Email";   

    //Your email will be displayed as HTML                   
    $mail->IsHTML(true);               

    // you can use HTML here                  
    $mail->Body="Hi, This <strong>is</strong> an email"; 

    //base64 encoding is applied here by default
    $mail->AddAttachment("path/to/file"); 

    //send the email               
    if ($mail->Send())
    {
         echo "Mail Sent";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Error sending mail: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

I usually use code very similar to this without any problems.  I hope this helps, and makes your life much simpler.  Just remember to include the PHP mailer library in the script, see the [tutorial here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial) for info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hay @Mikky you just need to adjust you code try this

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $position = $c;
    $name = $_POST['cName'];
    $telephone = $_POST['cTelephone'];
    $cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'];
    $myCv = $_FILES['upFile']['name'];

    $strTo = 'info@test.com';
    $strSubject = "Someone apply for career";
    $strMessage = nl2br("This information is for someone who apply for your new career\r\n
    Position Applied For:" . $position . ",\r\n
    His Name Is: " . $name . ",\r\n
    His Phone Number: " . $telephone . ",\r\n
    His Email: " . $cEmail . " \r\n");

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
    $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $strHeader = "";
    $strHeader .= "From:info@test.com\r\nReply-To:info@test.com";

    $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $strSid . "\"\n\n";
    $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

    $strHeader .= "--" . $strSid . "\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
    $strHeader .= $strMessage . "\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
    if ($_FILES['upFile']['name'] != "") {
        $strFilesName = $_FILES["upFile"]["name"];
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["upFile"]["tmp_name"])));
        $strHeader .= "--" . $strSid . "\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $strFilesName . "\"\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $strFilesName . "\"\n\n";
        $strHeader .= $strContent . "\n\n";
    }


    $flgSend = @mail($strTo, $strSubject, null, $strHeader); // @ = No Show Error //

    if ($flgSend) {
        header("Location:index.php?pid=17&msg=done");
    } else {
        echo "Cannot send mail.";
    }
}
?>
```

let me know if it's working now with you